# How should one make bulleted lists in Flex 4, given that "marginLeft" doesn't actually exist?

Tags: apache-flex

Gentlepersons,

Imagine wanting to display a bulleted list

- like
- this
- one

...using Adobe's Text Layout Framework (TLF) in Flex 4. How can one define such a bulleted list in MXML?

I understand that the current version of TLF does not yet implement support for bulleted lists.

That's OK, because I don't need my lists to be editable; they are display-only. This reduces the problem-space significantly, and should enable a solution to be kludged up.

A Google search reveals many suggestions to set a paragraph's marginLeft property to a negative number to get this effect. And indeed, Adobe Illustrator CS4, when saving a bullet-indented TextGraphic item in FXG, uses the marginLeft property.

However, using the MXML string whatever generates an error: "Cannot resolve attribute 'marginLeft' for component type flashx.textLayout.elements.ParagraphElement." So the "marginLeft" property does not actually seem to be implemented (or, more likely, I'm doing something wrong).

So, how should implement bulleted lists -- or more generally, hanging out-dents -- using Flex 4's TLF?

Thanks!  :-)

--- Jim

Answer (score 1):

See http://richardleggett.co.uk/blog/index.php/2009/02/24/bullet_points_align_text_layout_framewor

but basicaly you cheat.   You put each bullet in a span, start the span with a special character that looks like a bullet, and put some paddingLeft on each span.