# List Bullets in Flex 4.5

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5, flex-mobile

Is it possible to add bullets to a Label in Flex 4.5 mobile development?
something like this:

```
.Item
.Item
.Item
```

Comment: I'm not sure if your "Something like this" looks the way you anticipated it would.  Either that, or I really don't understand the problem you're having implementing that.

Comment: hope this link might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915764/how-should-one-make-bulleted-lists-in-flex-4-given-that-marginleft-doesnt-act

Answer (score 1):

I put an icon before the label

```
<s:List dataProvider="{items}">
  <s:itemRenderer>
    <fx:Component>
      <s:IconItemRenderer iconFunction="getIcon" label="{data.name}">
        <fx:Script> 
          <![CDATA[ 
            private function getIcon(item:Object):String
            { 
              return "assets/dot.png";
            } 
          ]]> 
        </fx:Script>
      </s:IconItemRenderer>
    </fx:Component>
  </s:itemRenderer>
</s:List>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extend a custom label component where in the createChildren() you add your image and place it -x from the left side of the label and adjust the y accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS19f279b149e7481c7fdc883d12de39353f1-8000.html

Comment: you should add answer descriptive